# How to store shader output to VRAM?

Tags: opengl, shaders

This is really ungrateful question to Google.

Basically, I would like to know, regarding openGL, what are various methods to do some kind of computation in one of the shaders and have the results stored in VRAM to be used and accessed at a later time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some helpful google-able terms will include:

render to a texture
use framebuffer object
read from a texture using glReadPixels

Hopefully by "computation" you mean "drawing" of some kind. Hope that helps!

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149512/opengl-how-to-read-back-texture-buffer